# Degree of a cone over the set of rank $r$ $n\times n$ matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Let $X_r\subset Mat_{n\times n}(C)$ denote the variety of rank at most $r$ matrices, set $k=n-r$ and assume $n\geq k^2-1$. Consider the cone over $X_r$ with vertex spanned by the first $k^2-1$ entries of the diagonal, that is consider the join of $X_r$ with the $k^2-1$ dimensional linear space spanned by those diagonal entries. Let $[k^k]$ denote the ${\frak S}_{k^2}$-module corresponding to the square Young diagram. The degree of the cone equals  $dim[k^k]*(n-\frac 12(k^2-1))$. Is there a geometric or representation-theoretic explanation for these dimensions? (For cones with smaller vertices there are similar, but more complicated formulae.)

Comment: Is there a motivation for this question?

Comment: The beauty of the answer hints that there is some interesting representation theory hidden in the variety. I'd like to understand it. I'd also like to have a geometrical proof of the result rather than the brute force calculation I have now.

Comment: Do you _really_ multiply by 2 for $k$ odd but divide by 2 for $k$ even? That's odd. And uneven.

Comment: Yes- the point is the number comes from an alternating sum of binomial coefficients, and when k is odd the middle one contributes, when k is even there is more cancellation. By the way, my previous question (which you (Allen) answered - thank you) was really a warm up to this one. One can interpolate between the two varieties by taking smaller and smaller vertices.

Comment: In the minimal case $n=k^2-1$, can't the $n-2k(k+1)$ go negative? Which wouldn't be so good for the degree.

Comment: you are correct- It is fixed now, thank you very much!

Comment: So $k$ is required odd now? Or is there supposed to be a floor somewhere?

Comment: No, it is now ok as written:  dim[k^k] will be a multiple of 2 (the apparent non-integrality problem was why I had originally written the cases differently and caused my error).